# How to make Multi-threading for multiple gameobjects moves in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, genetic-programming

I have a problem right now. I am creating a genetic programming AI for bomberman game.

My problem is related to threading; I want to execute my genomes simultaneously.

Here is an example:

I have a population

```
Genome[] population = //5 genomes for example
```

Each genome has an action or moves like
**UP**, **LEFT**, **RIGHT**, **DOWN**, **BOMB**

It produces random moves:

*Genome 1*
  RIGHT, BOMB, LEFT, UP, RIGHT ...

*Genome 2*
  LEFT, LEFT, RIGHT, LEFT, BOMB ...

*etc...*

Those moves or actions are working until the player is alive. I want to apply those move in my player (AI) using a thread.

I tried this:

```
for(Genome g in population){
     Thread thread = new Thread(g.run);
     thread.Start();
}
```

In run() method it produces the random moves and apply it to the gameobject which is the AI. For example, UP then go up. I used coroutine to do the action because those moves has an animation.

This game is realtime, moves are triggered every frame.

Is it possible to make all my genomes run simultaneously in separate thread? Possibly in another instance of the gameobject. I dont want my AI to get confused by those moves.

I have a possible solution but I don't know how to implement it.

Each genome has same information about the game, enemies, bomb, etc.
but their moves is different, for example:

5 computers with same game environment and same enemies.

However, each computer played by different AI (genome) with different moves that will get different result. In the first genome he died in early game after 3 seconds and the other genome died after 5 seconds. Then, the other is alive; something like that. I don't know if it is possible but can you give me some advise about my situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why use different threads?

Comment: i want to use thread because it runs in realtime. i want to get the very best moves from different result of each genome. like best moves is the one who survive the very long time and i also have a bunch of operations for those moves i don&#39;t want to freeze the game

Comment: I believe one thread would be fine for the purpose. Take note if you do proceed, the Unity API is not thread safe and calls to Unity API should only be done from the main thread, at least unless something changed since the source I provide was revised. Source: https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/208707516-Why-should-I-use-Threads-instead-of-Coroutines-

Comment: hello, can you watch this?
 https://youtu.be/8BBDFsomGYE

it something like this. i think the app uses multithreading because it produced a bunch of object with different behavior.

Comment: You don't need more threads to have objects with different behaviour, threading would be used to optimize the speed of calculations across multiple CPUs. As far as I know at least.

Comment: Okay, i will try and i hope it works

Comment: You can use multiple threads for calculations, it is more complex but might be faster. One thread should also work though.

Comment: Multiple threads are useful if you have a long-running, CPU intensive, calculation that can be broken into parts that can be **independently** processed. Short-running or dependent code will suffer terrible performance penalties when using threads. It doesn't sound like what you're doing would be a good use for threads. In other words, using threads would be **slower** here.

Comment: What's the point of this question? Were you struggling with creating Threads? Were you stuck somewhere? Your answer shows that you are simply creating a Thread which is a duplicate of many C# questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully created a thread for each genome inside a loop and it works.

```
foreach(Genome g in population)
{
    GP_Agent gp_agent = new GP_Agent();

    //passing the callback method, when the process is done then invoke the callback
    ThreadStart thread = delegate{
         gp_agent.next_move(g, callback);
    };
    thread.Invoke();
}

public void callback(String move){
     //apply the result move from the genome
    Debug.Log(genome.id + " = " +move);
}
```

as the result of this code. i got the moves from all genomes at the same time

*1 = UP*

*2 = DOWN*

*3 = LEFT*

when i apply those moves to the gameobject. the AI was confused because those moves are applying at the same time and that's what i want

Comment: Are you sure this works on all platforms? last time I checked Unity Does not support threads

Comment: You want the AI confused?

Comment: yes your right. Unity API is not thread safe that's why i use callback in which threads compute only the operations and after that in the callback method where i can use the produced data to the Unity API. i don't have any other solution and im in rush but if you can send me a links about another solution. it big helps for me thank you

Comment: i think i use a wrong word term. im bad in english. but i want to say is for the first time my AI doesn't know the game until he learn the game by evolution.

i use confused but i mean is moves are random and i'ts working at the same time i think i'ts parallel.
sorry for not being clear

Comment: if this solution worked for you, then you can already accept your answer.